# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.core.function.trace_type' has no attribute 'Serializable

Tags: python, tensorflow

error result:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.core.function.trace_type' has no attribute 'Serializable'

tryin to make tf record:

> import tensorflow as tf

using tensorflow 2.7

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.